# Al subir mi sistema a Ec2 en Amazon me dejan de andar las fechas y los puntos y comas

Tags: javascript, c#, aws, ec2, idioma

[image: Suma mal ejecutada en el hosting]

En mi localhost la suma se ejecuta correctamente, incluso tengo scripts de javascript en los cuales modifico comas y puntos para obtener lo que quiero... desde que subi el sistema a amazon no puedo hacer andar las sumas o montos de dinero con comas y puntos... tampoco me andan las fechas para elegir el datetimepicker del calentario, pienso que puede ser una configuracion regional, entonces me meti a la maquina virtual y modifique todos los idiomas regionales y de lenguaje en el escritorio remoto pero tampoco se soluciono, alguien tiene alguna solucion?

Comment: tipo de os utlizas, que servidor http,lenguaje backend ???

Comment: Back end C#, base Mysql, Servidor Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, tengo acceso remoto al mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Ahora resulta que agregando al webconfig

```
<system.web>
  <globalization culture="es-AR"
                 uiCulture="es-AR">
   </globalization>
</system.web>
```

ME esta andando bien el tema de las comas y numeros, incluso toma bien mis scripts en js, por ese lado solucionado! pero me siguen andando mal las fechas, elijo una fecha por ejemplo :

29 de noviembre de 2019

29/11/2019 y me dice: debe elegir una fecha superior a la actual, como si me tomase el dia por mes! es asi en estados unidos no ? Como puedo solucionar esto ?